# Pattern for widgets in unobstructive javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JS and jQuery for the first time after a lot of experience with Java and C++. I'm loving jQuery's idea of `$(document).on('click', 'btn-selector', react)`, but for more complex widgets I'm finding myself in the same rut over and over: in each `react` handler, I have to look up the widget as a whole and reconstruct all my knowledge about it.

For example, I'm making a simple widget out of `<input>`s with which the user can make a grading scale: 90 maps to an A, 80 maps to a B, etc.  When one of the inputs changes, I want to check to make sure that the inputs are still in order (your scale can't go 90, 70, 80, for example).

So, I have something like

## Actual

```
$(document).on('click', '.scale-input', function() {
    var widget = $(this).closest('.scale-widget-container');
    ensureLevelsAreInOrder(widget);
});
```

Almost every single handler has to have this first line to find its context.  I'd much rather have code that looks like this:

## Preferred

```
$(document).on('click', '.scale-input', ensureLevelsAreInOrder);
```

The problem is that in this form, `ensureLevelsAreInOrder` only has a reference to the input that changed, not the larger context.

In Java or C++, I would have called a constructor on the widget, and each input would have a handler with the context baked in via member variables.  I could do something similar with

```
$(function() {
    $('.scale-widget-container').scaleWidget();
});
```

with `scaleWidget()` setting up the contextualized handlers, but the page I'm working with loads a lot of its html with ajax and I don't have a reliable time to run that initialization.

Is this a common problem that we just have to deal with if we don't want JS in our HTML, or is there a solution I haven't come across yet?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what it is you're after *exactly*, but you don't seem to touch on two quite important concepts when it comes to JS: the `event` object, and closures. Both of these are open to you to get what you need:

*event object:*
The callback function is passed an argument, that describes the [event itself, and references the elements affected by that event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), This isn't exclusive to jQ (just google `addEventListener`), but it's quite handy:

```
$(document).on('click', '.scale-input', function(e)//<-- e is our event
{
    console.log(e);//check console
});
```

Which, in vanilla JS would look like this:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
    if (!e.className.test(/\bscale\-input\b/))
    {
        return e;
    }
    console.log(e);
}, false);
```

Another thing you might want to consider is enclosing references to whatever it is you need in an IIFE's scope:

```
(function()
{
    var containers = $('.scale-widget-container'),
    localBool = false,
    asMany = 'varsAs you need',
    previousScales = [],
    inputs = $('.scale-input');//references to all DOM nodes you mention
    $(document).on('click','.scale-input',function(e)
    {
        console.log($(this));
        console.log(containers);
        previousScales.push(this.value);//or something
        console.log(previousScales);
        //and so on.
    });
}());
```

Hope this helped

*Update:*
If IE isn't a browser you don't care about that much, you could use one of the DOM-modified events, specifically `DOMTreeModified`:

```
(function()
{
    var nodes = [];//<-- store current nodes here, if applicable
    nodes.containsNode = function(node)
    {
        var i;
        for (i=0;i<this.length;i++)
        {
            if (this[i] && this[i] === node)
            {//node is set, return its index
                return i;
            }
        }
        //node not found, return -1
        return -1;
    };
    document.body.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified',function(e)
    {
        var all = document.getElementsByClassName('scale-input'),
        i;
        for (i=0;i<all.length;i++)
        {
            if (nodes.containsNode(all[i]) === -1)
            {
                nodes.push(all[i]);//add new
            }
        }
    },false);
}());
```

More on the mutation events, and their issues, [on the DOM events wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Common.2FW3C_events)

Comment: This makes sense, and is really close to the constructor concept I need.  Unfortunately I don't think this will work for `scale-widget-container` elements added after this function runs.  This app loads most of its HTML by AJAX.  I could run this on the html inserted by each ajax call, but I'm hoping to avoid changing the app's core behavior.  Thanks for writing!

Comment: @RileyLark: I don't know if this is going to be an option, but perhaps you could add a couple of lines to the callback along the lines of `var loadedElems = Array.prototype.slice.apply($('.scale-widget-container'),[0]);` in the IIFE, and after each callback, check if the clicked element is in the `loadedElems` array. If so, good, if not `loadedElems.push($(this));` and keep the array up to date like so...

Comment: Shouldn't `}());` be `})();` at the very last part of your code?

Comment: @Johan the two structures are functionally identical.

Comment: @Johan: `}());` is Crockford's preferred notation because we want the function expression to be resolved to its return value, we have no use for the function itself, hence both the definition and the invocation are grouped together. That said, when I pass a DOM reference, using `getElementById`, I generally prefer `(function(bar){ return function(){};})(document.getElementById('foo'));`, because I find it more readable, and let JSLint moan about it anyways.

Comment: @RileyLark: Added another approach that might help you to keep the closure variables up-to-date. Perhaps there is a jQ equivalent that deals with X-browser issues, or perhaps you could expose a sort-of callback factory to pass all ajax responses to the closure, and let them deal with new nodes